# Docusign # of Envelopes Left

Tags: docusignapi

We have a docusign account and we have a number of envelopes we can use every year. Is there anyway to automate a check on this? I don't want to log in every few months to check. It's not that I'm lazy, but I feel like I may forget. Any API calls? Or maybe some email notification setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an API call that will retrieve related account information including billing periods, envelopes sent, etc.  The call you want to make is to a `GET` to the `/v2/accounts/{accountId}` URL.  This call is available in the [DocuSign API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/) under the **Account** tab:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "currentPlanId": "***",
  "planName": "DocuSign Enterprise",
  "planStartDate": "2013-06-17T18:52:47.8900000Z",
  "planEndDate": "2014-06-17T18:52:47.8900000Z",
  "billingPeriodStartDate": "2013-06-17T07:00:00.0000000Z",
  "billingPeriodEndDate": "2013-07-17T07:00:00.0000000Z",
  "billingPeriodEnvelopesSent": "132",
  "billingPeriodEnvelopesAllowed": "unlimited",
  "billingPeriodDaysRemaining": "0",
  "canUpgrade": "false",
  "canCancelRenewal": "true",
  "envelopeSendingBlocked": "false",
  "envelopeUnitPrice": "$0.00",
  "suspensionStatus": "",
  "accountName": "DocuSign",
  "connectPermission": "full",
  "docuSignLandingUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/products/sign_up/buy_now.php",
  "distributorCode": "***",
  "accountIdGuid": "***",
  "currencyCode": "USD",
  "forgottenPasswordQuestionsCount": "1",
  "paymentMethod": "purchase_order",
  "createdDate": "2013-06-17T18:52:47.0400000Z"
}
```

For more information on the *Get Account Information* API call see the REST API guide (page 71):

[DocuSign API Guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf#page=71)